# Adding line breaks in HTMLBody email code

Tags: excel, vba, email, line, break

When my email generates it doesn't have the line breaks despite using the `"& vbCrLf &"` code. I've tried using the `<br>` and `<p>` but I get compile errors every time.

Can someone please take a look at my code and help a brother out?

```
Dim strbody As String

    Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
    With xEmailObj
        .Display
        .to = xMemberName5
        .CC = ""
        .Subject = "Annual Review " + xMemberName + " " + "Cust " + xMemberName3
        strbody = "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:11pt;color:rgb(31,78,121)'>" + xMemberName7 + "," _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Our records indicate that " + xMemberName + " is due for an annual pricing review. We are seeking an overall impact of " + xMemberName6 + "% increase to the rates. Updated Tariff page is attached." _
        & vbCrLf & "If there are any pricing issues which need to be addressed, please get back to me no later than " & CDate(Date + 7) & "." _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Otherwise, the attached new pricing will be effective " + xMemberName4 + ". I encourage you to visit with your customer and deliver the new pricing ASAP." & .HTMLBody & "</body>"
        .HTMLBody = strbody
```

Comment: `<br` should work. Put it in quotes like `"<br>"`.

Comment: ...or declare a constant: `Const Break = "<br>"` and then use that instead of `vbCrLf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include the `<br>`directly in your string as you did with `<p>` already

```
    strbody = "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:11pt;color:rgb(31,78,121)'>" & xMemberName7 & "," _
    & "<br><br>Our records indicate that " & xMemberName & " is due for an annual pricing review. We are seeking an overall impact of " & xMemberName6 & "% increase to the rates. Updated Tariff page is attached." _
    & "<br>If there are any pricing issues which need to be addressed, please get back to me no later than " & CDate(Date + 7) & "." _
    & "<br><br>Otherwise, the attached new pricing will be effective " & xMemberName4 & ". I encourage you to visit with your customer and deliver the new pricing ASAP." & .HTMLBody & "</body>"
```

And I recommend to use `&` instead of `+` to concatenate your variables with strings.

Comment: "Just include the <br>directly in your string as you did with <p> already"
This fixed it, thanks a ton Peh!